# Maximal torus of a positive dimensional compact Lie group is nontrivial?

Tags: lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group. A *torus* in $G$ is a subgroup $T \leq G$ isomorphic to $(S^1)^n$ for some $n \geq 0$, where we set $(S^1)^0 = \{*\}$ which is the trivial torus.

A standard theorem asserts the existence of a *maximal torus* $T$ in $G$, can it be trivial when $G$ has positive dimension? Why not?

Comment: The closure of an abelian subgroup is again an abelian subgroup. Does $G$ have nontrivial connected abelian subgroups?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that helps. A trivial torus is closed because the Lie group is a Hausdorff space, isn't it? So starting with a trivial torus, I don't see why it has to be contained in a larger one.

Comment: Don't start with a torus, start with a nontrivial connected abelian subgroup. And look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597986/classify-the-compact-abelian-lie-groups) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396822/a-compact-connected-abelian-lie-group-is-a-torus). Plus [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_subgroup_theorem).